# getting the org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException while installing UX studio software in eclipse

Tags: salesforce, eclipse-mars

I am trying to install UX_ Studio software in eclipse from the following URl.

http://developer.salesforce.com/media/commercecloud/uxstudio/4.5

This is my home pc

But I am getting the **org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException**

The error is as follows:

> Unable to read repository at http://developer.salesforce.com/media/commercecloud/uxstudio/4.5/content.xml.
>   Unable to read repository at http://developer.salesforce.com/media/commercecloud/uxstudio/4.5/content.xml.
>   Received fatal alert: protocol_version

I checked the error online and added the following line 
 open the eclipse.ini file and add the following on a separate line under the -vmargs option.
**-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true**

But exception is still there

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 needs to install with the software. Other versions of java will not work